# Get certain row from html table with JMeter

Tags: html, xpath, html-table, jmeter

I have a table in HTML. In one row, I have numerous data like name, email, URL, date, etc:

```
<td>
    <a href="mywebsite.com/events/634" title="Show">15</a>
</td>
<td>2017-07-18 11:00</td>
<td>Teszt SK</td>
<td>Test Trevor<small></small></td>
<td>2017-07-18 12:00</td>
<td><span class="label label-primary">Already in</span></td>
```

I wish to get the last part of the URL where the name equals my `${name}` variable.

The URL looks like: `http<nolink>://mywerbsite.com/event/123`

So what I wish to get is the 123 and put it into my `${eventid}` variable.

The problem is the fact, that there are usually more than one events for the users. So I want JMeter to stop at the first found. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant XPath Expression would be something like:

```
substring-after(//td[text()='Test Trevor']/parent::*/td/a/@href,'events/')
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Xpath Demo]

References:

- [XSLT, XPath, and XQuery Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp)
- [XPath `substring-after` function reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: Can I use `${name}` instead of Test Trevor in this?

Comment: Also, if I just use the developer tool of Chrome, right click and get my XPath for the value I'm looking for? If I do this for the name on the site, I get the following:

`//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/text()`

So if I'm reading the manuals right, I'll need the **substring-after** function. Is this supposed to be correct then?

`substring-after('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/${name}','events/')`

Comment: The URL Xpath is this extracted from Chrome: `//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a`

Answer (score 0):

Add regular expression as post processor of request

regular expression: mywebsite.com/events/(\d+)" (.*)Test Trevor

Template $1$

Match No. 1

It will return the first row (checked)

Comment: The 1st row is not always the correct one. If multiple users create the events, then the second creators event will be on top. I wanted to check the name which is in this case Test Trevor and get the ID of Trevors event only.

Comment: Fix solution for specific name

Comment: Still nope. :/ The ${eventid} variable seems to be still empty cause when I try to go to an URL `mywerbsite.com/events/${eventid}/create_report` I literally get the variable back, not it's value. The last part `(.*)Test Trevor` messes up the script

Comment: It work in my test, try: mywebsite.com\/events\/(\d+)" (.*)Test Trevor

Comment: Still nope. :/ Strange that without the name search it works, but as I've said, that is not always giving the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a few tries, I've came up with a quite complicated answer but it sure works. Some minor tweaks are still needed, but it works. Here are some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]